# Trigger event on certificate renewed, replaced

Tags: powershell, certificate, windows-server-2012

I am attempting to trigger a task schedule to kick off a powershell script based on when a new certificate is added into the `Local Computer\Personal\Certificates` store.

For testing purposes, the certificates, are self-signed, created using openssl.

As the certificates are generated, non-[pkcs12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/pkcs12) do not trigger the event found in event viewer's `Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational`.

However, the pkcs12 certificates do.

Any ideas how to get non-pkcs12 certificates to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

How about having a script that is called periodically that writes the thumbprints of all existing certs to a file?  Each time it runs, if a new thumbprint is found that isn't in the file, it can trigger whatever the rest of your script needs to do, and update the file.

```
$file = ".\certsSeenBefore.txt"
# make sure the above file exists
If (-not (Test-Path $file)) { New-Item $file -ItemType File }

# for each cert, see if the thumbprint is in the file
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | foreach {
    if ((Get-Content($file)) -contains $_.Thumbprint)
    {
        # all good
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Ah Ha! THere's a new cert $_.Subject"

        # Add the thumbprint to the file so it doesn't get triggered again.
        Add-Content $file -Value $_.Thumbprint

        # call whatever it is you need to do

        # ....

    }
}
```

Apologies, I know this isn't a complete answer, but don't have enough foo to be able to comment.